# What does `General` mean in Chrome browser dev tools when debug the HTTP request?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to debug the HTTP request with Chrome browser dev tools.
When I click a GET request, I see several parts including General, Request Headers, etc.

I find out many articles said the General part means HTTP Common Headers which can be used as Request header or Response header, while I think it doesn't make sense.

I suppose the General part is just a simple description or summary of the request and response.

I try to find the result on the [official document](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/reference/#headers) but couldn't find it.

Sorry for my English. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: It just a title for the information that is not under request/response headers or parameters.

Comment: @sabasabo Thanks for your reply. So it is just the information and doesn't have anything to do with HTTP headers, right? Because I can't find any HTTP headers named 'Request URL', 'Request Method'.

Comment: I think it includes some of the headers that usually people need to check more frequently, so they've put it there at the top so you'll be able to see them as soon as you open this Headers subtab.